# populating menus from multiple collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, express, socket.io

I'm new to backbone.js and express and I have been adapting Christophe Coenraets Wine Cellar REST API example application for my own project.

I am building a form that has several menus needing to be populated from multiple unrelated collections in mongodb.

I am able to populate one menu with one collection, but I have no idea how to get more than one collection to my form View.

Here are the files I am using to populate one menu. How do I expand this to populate two menus?

I suppose I could make a new View for every menu I want to populate - but that seems like overkill.

Can I combine two mongodb find() collections into one object, and list them separately on a page? If so, how?

thanks in advance!

/routes/modules.js contains:

> exports.findAllModules = function(req, res) {
>
> ```
> db.collection('modules', function(err, collection) {
>
>     collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
>
>         res.send(items);
>
>     });
>
> });
> ```
>
> };

/server.js contains:

> app.get('/modules', module.findAllModules);

/public/js/main.js contains:

> routes: {
>
> "modules" : "list" }

...

> list: function(page) {
>
> ```
>     var p = page ? parseInt(page, 10) : 1;
>
>     var moduleList = new ModuleCollection();
>
>     moduleList.fetch({success: function(){
>
>         console.log('in list function');
>
>         $("#content").html(new ModuleListView({model: moduleList, page: p}).el);
>
>     }});
>
>     this.headerView.selectMenuItem('home-menu');
>
> },
> ```

...

> utils.loadTemplate([
>
> ```
> 'ModuleListItemView' ], function() {
>
> app = new AppRouter();
>
> Backbone.history.start(); });
> ```

/public/models/models.js contains:

> window.Module = Backbone.Model.extend({
>
> ```
> urlRoot: "/modules",
>
> idAttribute: "_id",
>
> initialize: function () {
>     this.validators = {};
>
>     this.validators.name = function (value) {
>         return value.length > 0 ? {isValid: true} : {isValid: false, message: "You must enter a name"};
>     };
>
> validateItem: function (key) {
>     return (this.validators[key]) ? this.validators[key](this.get(key)) : {isValid: true};
> },
> validateAll: function () {
>     var messages = {};
>
>     for (var key in this.validators) {
>         if(this.validators.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
>             var check = this.validators[key](this.get(key));
>             if (check.isValid === false) {
>                 messages[key] = check.message;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return _.size(messages) > 0 ? {isValid: false, messages: messages} : {isValid: true};
> },
>
> defaults: {
>     _id: null,
>     name: ""
> } });
> ```
>
> window.ModuleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
>
> ```
> model: Module,
>
> url: "/modules"
> ```
>
> });

/public/js/views/modulelist.js contains:

> window.ModuleListView = Backbone.View.extend({
>
> ```
> initialize: function () {
>     this.render();
> },
>
> render: function () {
>     var modules = this.model.models;
>
>     $(this.el).html('<ul class="thumbnails"></ul>');
>
>     for (var i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
>         $('.thumbnails', this.el).append(new ModuleListItemView({model: modules[i]}).render().el);
>     }
>     return this;
> } });
> ```
>
> window.ModuleListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
>
> ```
> tagName: "li",
>
> initialize: function () {
>
>     this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
>
>     this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
>
> },
>
> render: function () {
>
>     $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
>
>     return this;
>
> } });
> ```

/public/tpl/ModuleListView.html contains:

> 

Comment: Have you considered creating a Model to manage all the collection, attaching it to the view and passing only the desired data?

Comment: thanks @iMoses, that sounds like a good solution, but I'm still confused about the architecture. This is what I think is happening: 1. Modules.js exports the database call. 2. server.js uses app.get to send the data to the model depending on the URL path 3. Model uses this.model.models to access the data. I've tried using app.get twice to the same URL path, but only the first call gets to the model. So, my question still remains - how do I get two collections to the model, and once its there how do I access it? Like "this.model.options.module1" and "this.model.options.module 2?

Comment: I don't quite get it. `/modules` path returns a list of modules which are entered into a collection and passed to the view as a model. So first of all, if you are using a collection then pass it to the view as a collection. Secondly, are you expecting an ID using the path, as such `/modules/id`? Does it return an item instead of a list?

Comment: @iMoses, Yes /modules returns a list of modules and ModulesView.html loads with the list. If an id is present, then ModulesListItemView.html loads with a single item instead of a list.

Comment: And do you wish to fetch more then one modules list? What's wrong with the initial data you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure how your code works, but here are a few backbone tips.

If you wanna build a menu from a collection don't pass the collection as a model.

Instead of:

```
    $("#content").html(new ModuleListView({model: moduleList, page: p}).el);
```

Use:

```
    $("#content").empty().append(new ModuleListView({collection: moduleList, page: p}).el);
```

Instead of:

```
render: function () {
    var modules = this.model.models;

    $(this.el).html('<ul class="thumbnails"></ul>');

    for (var i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
        $('.thumbnails', this.el).append(new ModuleListItemView({model: modules[i]}).render().el);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Use:

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html('<ul class="thumbnails">');

    this.collection.each(function(model) {
        this.$('.thumbnails').append(new ModuleListItemView({model: model}).render().el);
    }, this);

    return this;
}
```

If you have no need in updating or deleting your models, it's enough to add the url path `/modules` only to the collection, for reading the initial modules.

Comment: I added the new code, and the app still works, so it's a start.

Comment: I added the new code, and the app still works, so it's a start. If I want access to a second collection when the ModuleListItemView loads, to populate a menu of unrelated data, for instance, without correlation to this collection... Do I need to make a new model and new view for every database call? I still think my hang-up is the app.get function in the server.js file - It seems like I can only send one collection per URL path /modules. If I add /modules/:id, I load a second view, as second URL path. But I want to send multiple collections to a single URL path.

Comment: AHA! It was in the main.js - I added another 

$("#content").empty().append(new ModuleListView({collection: moduleList, page: p}).el);

fixed the URLS and it worked. Thanks !!!